# Go memory allocation - new objects, pointers and escape analysis

Tags: go, memory

I read that Golang language manages memory in a smart way. Using escape analysis, go may not allocate memory when calling new, and vice versa. Can golang allocate memory with such a notation `var bob * Person = & Person {2, 3}`. Or always the pointer will point to the stack

Comment: That style will be new allocated if it escapes. It may be inlined up into the parent's stack. It may be a stack pointer or it may be optimized away if it doesn't escape its stack scope (after inlining).

Comment: Go the language has no notion of "heap" or "stack", only certain implementations for certain platforms do. This is entirely dependent on the compiler version and the  architecture you compile your code for. E.g. it might make nor sense to ask this if you set GOARCH=wasm. Note that this might change on every compiler version and even be different between platforms or implementations (e.g. gcc and gcc could do differently).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The pointer may escape to the heap, or it may not, depends on your use case. The compiler is pretty smart. E.g. given:

```
type Person struct {
    b, c int
}


func foo(b, c int) int {
    bob := &Person{b, c}
    return bob.b
}
```

The function `foo` will be compiled into:

```
    TEXT    "".foo(SB)
    MOVQ    "".b+8(SP), AX
    MOVQ    AX, "".~r2+24(SP)
    RET
```

It's all on the stack here, because even though `bob` is a pointer, it doesn't escape this function's scope.

However, if we consider a slight (albeit artificial) modification:

```
var globalBob *Person

func foo(b, c int) int {
    bob := &Person{b, c}
    globalBob = bob
    return bob.b
}
```

Then `bob` escapes, and `foo` will be compiled to:

```
    TEXT    "".foo(SB), ABIInternal, $24-24
    MOVQ    (TLS), CX
    CMPQ    SP, 16(CX)
    PCDATA  $0, $-2
    JLS     foo_pc115
    PCDATA  $0, $-1
    SUBQ    $24, SP
    MOVQ    BP, 16(SP)
    LEAQ    16(SP), BP
    LEAQ    type."".Person(SB), AX
    MOVQ    AX, (SP)
    PCDATA  $1, $0
    CALL    runtime.newobject(SB)
    MOVQ    8(SP), AX
    MOVQ    "".b+32(SP), CX
    MOVQ    CX, (AX)
    MOVQ    "".c+40(SP), CX
    MOVQ    CX, 8(AX)
    PCDATA  $0, $-2
    CMPL    runtime.writeBarrier(SB), $0
    JNE     foo_pc101
    MOVQ    AX, "".globalBob(SB)
 foo_pc83:
    PCDATA  $0, $-1
    MOVQ    (AX), AX
    MOVQ    AX, "".~r2+48(SP)
    MOVQ    16(SP), BP
    ADDQ    $24, SP
    RET
```

Which, as you can see, invokes `newobject`.

---

These disassembly listings were generated by https://godbolt.org/, and are for go 1.16 on amd64

Answer (score 2):

Whether memory is allocated on the stack or "escapes" to the heap is entirely dependent on how you use the memory, not on how you declare the variable.

If you return a pointer to a stack-allocated variable in, say, C, the value your pointer will be invalid by the time you attempt to use it. This isn't possible in Go, because you cannot explicitly tell Go where to place a variable. It does a very good job of choosing the correct place, and if it sees that references to a blob of memory *may* live beyond the stack frame, it will ensure that allocation happens on the heap instead.

> Can golang allocate memory with such a notation
>
> `var bob * Person = & Person {2, 3}`
>
> Or always the pointer will point to the stack

That line of code **cannot** be said "always" point to the stack, but it might sometimes, so yes, it *may* allocate memory (on the heap).

Again, it's not about that line of code, it's about what comes after it. If value of `bob` is returned (the address of the `Person` object) then it cannot be allocated on the stack because the returned address would point to reclaimed memory.

Answer (score 2):

Put simply, if the compiler can **prove** that the value can safely be created on the stack, it will (probably) be created on the stack. Otherwise, it will be allocated on the heap.

The tools that the compiler has to do these proofs are pretty good, but it doesn't get it right all the time. Most of the time, though, cost vs benefit of worrying about it is not really benefitial.